# Recursive function outputs a wrong value

Tags: c++, recursion, division, addition, exponential

**In this code the output is 'r' instead of 'r0'**

Instead of doing the operations it outputs me the first 'r' (equals 100) and does not do the process.
I´m trying to program an operation like (x_0 = x + (nt²/(2(x+(n(t-1)²/2(x+(n(t-3)²/2(x + (n(t-4)²...)²)²)²)²)²)²)²)²) in where the process is repeated until the variable 't' is '0'(because each time the operation is done 't' get a '-1').

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
using namespace std;
int operation(float r,
float r0,
float recursiva,
float operacion,
float recursivaPrincipal2,
float recursivaPrincipal,
float p,
float n,
long long t,
float q,
float potenciaQ,
float c,
float potenciaC,
float t2,
float division);

float r = 100;
float t = 10000;
float r0;
float recursiva;
float operacion;
float recursivaPrincipal2;
float recursivaPrincipal;
float p;
float n;
float q;
float potenciaQ;
float c;
float potenciaC;
float t2;
float division;

int main() {
    r0 = r + operacion;
    potenciaQ = pow(10,10);
    q = 6 * potenciaQ;
    potenciaC = pow(10,2);
    c =  5 * potenciaC;
    while (t = 10000, t = t - 1, t > 0) {
        t2 = t * t;
        n = q * t2;
        operacion = n / recursivaPrincipal;
        recursivaPrincipal2 = recursiva * recursiva;
        recursivaPrincipal = 2 * recursivaPrincipal2;
        recursiva = r + operacion;
        if (t == 0) {
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
        cout << "Solucion: " << r0 << endl;
    }
}
```

[i want to do something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNRh4.jpg)

I'm so sorry if this code offended you (comments look like it) but I'm not very good, this is my first c++ code (and last I think)

Comment: A function that takes fourteen arguments is almost certainly wrong. And having global variables with the same names as those arguments is also almost certainly wrong. But that function isn’t defined or called, so it doesn’t affect this code.

Comment: I doubt this does what you think it does `while (t = 10000, t = t - 1, t > 0) {`. Seems like what you are looking for is `for (t = 10000; t > 0; t = t - 1) {`

Comment: Please indent the code, so it is readable; get rid of global variables; don't pass so many parameters (maybe define a struct);  use meaningful names, not p,n,q,t2; it's confusing to have both `operation` and `operacion`

Comment: That `while` loop is definitely wrong. `t = 1000` sets `t` to 1000. Okay so far. `, t = t - 1` now sets `t` to 999. And finally `, t > 0` will always be true, because the value of `t` is 999.

Comment: My eyes! The goggles do nothing

Comment: Even if the loop is fixed, your solution which is in r0 is never updated inside the loop or after the loop so what does the loop do then ?

Comment: I'm new to this, sorry, but this if my first code in C++

Comment: @PeteBecker i want to do an operation to do (for example setting 't' as 10) t(now is 10)/(something + (t(now 9)/(something+(t(now 8)...(and repeat the process until we have 't' = 0))²)²

Comment: That's probably a `for` loop, not a `while` loop. `for (t = 1000; t > 0; t = t - 1)`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I have re-wrote the code, want to see it?

Comment: By the way @PeteBecker how can I do a loop like: for (t = 1000; t > 0; t--) that makes t=999, then 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, ...?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on what i get from your question

**Please do expand your mathematical expression for t=3 and append an image of it**

*by far what i got from your expression you need this*

```
float func(int t,int n,int x)
 {
  if (t==1)
  {
   return (x + (n/2)*(n/2)) * (x + (n/2)*(n/2));
  }

  return x + (n*t*t)/(2*func(t-1,n,x)) ;
 }
```

*According to the picture you have uploaded  this is my code*

**Don't use 0 for n**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

double partSolver(int x,int p, int n)
{
   if(n==0)  return 2*x*x;
   double val = x - ( (p*n*n) / partSolver(x,p,n-1) );
   return 2*val*val ;
}

double solver(int x,int p,int n)
{
   return (n*n * 2) / partSolver(x,p,n-1);
}

int main()
 {
  cout<<"The Solution is: "<<solver(3,2,1)<<endl;

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Be careful with integer division.

Comment: yeah i wrote that in hurry. The author of question hasn't made it clear exactly what he needs

Comment: I can't expand it because 't' is 1000

Comment: @RoushanSingh yeah, I know, I have just uploaded a photo of the equation I'm trying to represent.

Comment: @Roushan Singh so that division won't stop dividing until n = 0?

Comment: when when becomes 0 it evaluates to  2*x**x  as  2*(x- p*0*0)^2